# Position of indicator in mat-tree Angular

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I want to change indicator position. I didn't find anything in documentation about it. Here is a 
[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/angular/eyndvypqapa?file=app%2Ftree-flat-overview-example.ts) from angular material docs.
I want to have indicator on the right side of title, at every level of tree.
Thanks for help:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `label` first then the `button` inside your `HTML file` as shown below.

```
 <mat-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node;when: hasChild" matTreeNodePadding>
   {{node.name}}
   <button mat-icon-button matTreeNodeToggle
        [attr.aria-label]="'toggle ' + node.name">
   <mat-icon class="mat-icon-rtl-mirror">
      {{treeControl.isExpanded(node) ? 'expand_more' : 'chevron_right'}}
    </mat-icon>
  </button>
```

I have updated your code [here in stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/angular/eyndvypqapa?file=app%2Ftree-flat-overview-example.html).

Answer (score 0):

Just change the position of the label before the button

```
{{node.name}}
<button mat-icon-button matTreeNodeToggle [attr.aria-label]="'toggle ' + node.name">
  <mat-icon class="mat-icon-rtl-mirror">
    {{treeControl.isExpanded(node) ? 'expand_more' : 'chevron_right'}}
  </mat-icon>
</button>
```